# Problema com android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Estou desenvolvendo em flutter, eu consigo abrir o android studio normalmente, até consigo abrir o emulador também, porém quando vou executar o app nesse emulador aberto o android studio trava o computador todo e nada funciona mais, nem o mouse e nem nada do pc, só consegue sair desse congelamento apertando o botão de energia, eu já instalei uma versão antiga do android studio e o erro continua, alguém sabe o que pode ser ?

Comment: Outra coisa que eu queria saber, é se caso eu não consiga resolver esse problema, tem como usar o vs code pra desenvolver em android nativo com kotlin ?